# How to get a delay into this loop?

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft

I was trying to update the point where a compass would point with a loop, but the delay doesn't work and it lags the server out. Neither `TimeUnit` or `Thread` or `wait()` worked. I used spigot 1.14.4.

```
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;
import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.Location;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Main extends JavaPlugin{
    @Override
    public void onEnable(){
    }
    @Override
    public void onDisable() {   
    }
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command command, String label, String[] args) {
        //target <player-name>
        if(args.length>=1) {
            if(Bukkit.getPlayerExact(args[0])!=null) {
                Player target=Bukkit.getPlayer(args[0]);
                Player p=(Player) sender;
                sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.BLUE + "Compass assigned to" + target);
                while(Bukkit.getPlayerExact(args[0])!=null) {
                    Location loc = target.getLocation();
                    p.setCompassTarget(loc);
                    try {
                        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                }else{
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.BLUE + "Invalid Player");
                }   
            }else{
                sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.BLUE + "Choose a player"); 
        }
    return false;
    }
}
```

Maybe there is some special way to do it, or should it be an event of some kind or?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can create a thread around it and let it sleep.

```java
Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {

Thread.sleep(1500)
//code

});
thread.start();
```